# Converting string that looks like a list into a real list - python

Tags: python, string, list, int, tuples

My input files have lines that looks like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
[(0, 1, 6), (1, 3,7), (3, 1,4), (3, 1,3), (8, 1,2)]
[1,2,3,5,3]
```

There are no letters, no decimals, only integers and number of element in tuples will be consistent.

How do i make them into real list of tuples / list of int?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included - that problem is solved by [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]")
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
>>> ast.literal_eval("[(0, 1, 6), (1, 3,7), (3, 1,4), (3, 1,3), (8, 1,2)]")
[(0, 1, 6), (1, 3, 7), (3, 1, 4), (3, 1, 3), (8, 1, 2)]
>>> ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3,5,3]")
[1, 2, 3, 5, 3]
```

Comment: @alvas:  Please note that `ast.literal_eval` is safe whereas `eval` is not.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Why is ast.literal_eval safe and eval not safe?

Comment: @jeppo1: Often the string you are wanting to evaluate comes from an untrusted source.  `eval` will run arbitrary code.  Running arbitrary code from third parties is a security hole.  `ast.literal_eval`, plugs that hold because it only interprets "strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None."  Anything else is an error.