# Converting numpy array to a list

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert a numpy array to list.

input is :

```
s = [ 6.72599983 -7.15100002  4.68499994]
```

i want output as :

```
s = [6.72599983, -7.15100002, 4.68499994]
```

how I will do this in python?

Comment: Doesn't look *too* hard ... have you made any attempts?

Comment: yes it has type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string that looks like a list into a real list - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250396/converting-string-that-looks-like-a-list-into-a-real-list-python)

Comment: Then you don't have a `string`, you have a numpy array -- to get a list, simply use `list(s)`.  But if you thought you had a string, maybe you don't need to convert it... arrays are pretty good too :)

Comment: its not duplicate. please dt downvote unnecessarily

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - convert string to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266529/python-convert-string-to-list)

Comment: can you check my question properly first?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but you are also not asking the actual question you're asking. You're not asking how to convert a string to a list, but a numpy.ndarray to a list, which is extremely trivial.

Comment: oh ok i may have made mistake asking question properly but inside i wrote properly.

Comment: Okay, here. Please just try printing it in a console session and show the result to us.

Comment: type is : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @sam **You** should write the question properly. If *s* is `numpy.ndarray` why the *hell* do you write that it is a string and make up the code in the question to make sure to hide this? -1 -- learn to *at least* search [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) before asking a question.

Comment: @Bakuriu : aha ok i made mistake their. sorry i wil update

Comment: @sam Can you include the result of `print s`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `numpy.ndarray`, then try this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> lst = [6.72599983, -7.15100002, 4.68499994]
>>> numpy.asarray(lst)
array([ 6.72599983, -7.15100002,  4.68499994])
>>> list(numpy.asarray(lst))
[6.7259998300000001, -7.1510000199999997, 4.68499994]
```

If you have wrongly casted the `numpy.array` into a string, then you need to use that cleaning trick with ast to get it into a list.

```
>>> import ast, numpy
>>> s = str(numpy.asarray(lst))
>>> s
'[ 6.72599983 -7.15100002  4.68499994]'
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(",".join(s.split()).replace("[,", "[")))
[6.72599983, -7.15100002, 4.68499994]
```

Comment: It's missing the commas.  `ast` won't help

Comment: @mgilson, edited, i was typing too slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question still is quite unclear.

If `s` is really of type 'numpy.ndarray' and not a string (as the older version of your question suggested), then just do

```
s = list(s)
```

and `s` will become a list.

Answer (score 0):

`s.split()` should work.

You can find solution here: [Python - convert string to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266529/python-convert-string-to-list)