# How to convert string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it even possible, and if it is, how could I do something like this. Imagine you run this code and type in the input ["Hello","Sup"]

```py
list = input()
something = list[0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Could you specify what you want for your output in this example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250396/converting-string-that-looks-like-a-list-into-a-real-list-python

Answer (score 0):

If the user is inputting a string of words separated by spaces, you can call do

```
something = str(list).split(" ")
```

This will encounter errors though if the user inputs something other than a string...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could remove "["s and "]"s and then `split` it, which will return an actual list.

`list.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split()`

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple with Python.

Just use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and you're fine.

```
import ast

string_to_be_converted = '[ "I", "am", "a", "string"]'

mylist = ast.literal_eval(string_to_be_converted)
```

Here, `type(mylist)` shows us that `mylist` is a `list`, not a `string`.

However, **I recommend using [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)** for such an operation. Not only it is more secure, but also **way faster**.

```
import json

string_to_be_converted = '[ "I", "am", "a", "string"]'

mylist = json.loads(string_to_be_converted)
```

**Speed comparison:**

**Ast:**

```
In [1]: %timeit ast.literal_eval(string_to_be_converted)
13.6 µs per loop
```

**Json:**

```
In [2]: %timeit json.loads(string_to_be_converted)
2.99 µs per loop
```